# Why does the InternalsPublicTo Attribute require a full public key?

Tags: .net, strongname

For the [InternalsPublicTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute, it makes sense that a strongly-named assembly must refer to another strongly-named assembly.  However, it seems that this attribute is unusual in that it requires you to specify the full public key and not just the public key token that many similar linking mechanisms require.  What are the advantages of requiring the full public key, and why don't they apply to other similar mechanisms (like the assembly linking)?